# Setting the camera in Starcraft 2 to be like Warcraft 3 or Dota 2

Tags: starcraft-2, dota-2, mouse, autohotkey

In SC2, the WC3/DotA 2 Mouse3 dragging has been removed. Instead, when you hold Mouse3 and move the screen, the mouse reappears where you started dragging from.

On WC3 and DotA 2, it started from where you wanted it to, and ended where you stopped with it on the screen.

How can I setup the camera in Starcraft 2 to be like Warcraft 3 or Dota 2? Maybe Autohotkey can help me?

Comment: A question about "how to setup mouse control" is perfectly on-topic here, it is "why" part what is causing those votes to close.

Comment: I do not know of a way to retrofit drag scrolling to style of WC3, and Autohotkey would not help too, most likely. It is impossible to "unlock" the cursor from where the game wants it, and issuing keyboard scroll commands from Autohotkey would be very unreliable.

Comment: On the other hand, what is wrong with cursor being frozen? I'd say it is better when it's kept closer to the center of the screen where you click the most, and you can scroll farther when you aren't bound by edges of the screen...